# Comunicação com a porta COM3

Tags: delphi-7

Estou tentando ler o retorno de uma acesso á porta **COM3** que é onde está o modem 56kbps antigo.

A comunicação está sendo feita e o modem está lugando e recebendo chamadas de fora!

Porém gostaria de ler os dados que o modem possa me enviar.

A conexão à porta do modem fiz assim:

```
...

hCommFile: THandle;
Status: LongBool;
NumberWritten: DWORD;
Buf : array[0..1023] of Byte;
s :string;

.......

//Abre a porta de comunicação
s:='COM3';
hCommFile := CreateFile (
                     PChar(s),
                     GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
                     0, // não compartilhado
                     nil, // sem segurança
                     OPEN_EXISTING,
                     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                     0);

// Verifica a abertura da porta
if hCommFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
begin

//Envia a String de Comando
NumberWritten:=0;
Status:= WriteFile(
                    hCommFile,
                    PChar(s)[0],
                    Length(s),
                    NumberWritten,
                    nil);

...
```

Até aqui tudo certo.
Mas estou tentando pegar dados dos modem.
Acho que é preciso usar a **classe** `inputStream` mas não acho nada para **Delphi**.

Tentei assim mas o código travou

```
if FileRead(hCommFile, Buf[0], 1023) = 1 then
begin
   ShowMessage('a');
end;

....
```

Alguém ajuda.

O objetivo é pegar um retorno apenas e jogar em uma variável!

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou usar o Comport?

https://pt.osdn.net/projects/sfnet_comport/downloads/comport/4.11/comport411f.zip/

É um componente muito bom e vai evitar uma série de problemas.